# Can I externalize parts of a Rust documentation test to an external file?

Tags: rust, rustdoc

When writing Rust documentation tests, is it possible to externalize parts of the code to an external file to keep the example short?

Comment: *why?* If the code is relevant to the example, show it. If it's not relevant to the example, just [prefix the lines with `#` to hide them](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/first-edition/documentation.html): *you can add lines that start with `#`, and they will be hidden from the output, but will be used when compiling your code*

Comment: I was thinking that I could extract non relevant parts into that file. Otherwise it will boat up the documentation to only be readable when rendered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`# include!("src/fragment.rs")` appears to work and does not show up in the output.  I have no idea how this interferes with Cargo's dependency processing, though.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is officially supported at this moment; there is a related [Cargo issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/cargo/issues/739) and [a tool](https://github.com/Geal/cargo-external-doc) that attempts to allow it until it is introduced in Cargo (I haven't used it, though).